# What is the difference between sizeof(x) and sizeof(p_x)

Tags: c

Can u tell me what is the difference between `sizeof(x)` and `sizeof(p_x)` in the code below?

```
int x[10], *p_x;
p_x = (int*)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: The fact that you allocated `10*sizeof(int)` to `p_x` has no effect on `sizeof`, which is evaluated at compile time in this case.

Comment: `p_x = malloc (10 * sizeof (* p_x))` (without a cast) would have been preferable — `sizeof (* p_x)` is the size of what `p_x` points at. And if you had declared `p_x` as a pointer to an `int [10]`, then `sizeof (* p_x)` would have been exactly the right size.

Answer (score 9):

```
sizeof(x)
```

is giving the number of bytes used by the array `x`.

```
sizeof(p_x)
```

is giving the number of bytes used by a pointer.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x[10], *p_x;
    printf ("%lu %lu\n", (unsigned long)sizeof(x), (unsigned long)sizeof(p_x));
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
40 4
```

My MSVC uses 32-bit pointers and 32-bit ints.

**EDIT** improved number formatting following below comments, thanks.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I take your point thank you, but my MSVC does not understand `%zu` format specifier.

Comment: Oops, I did not realize MSVC was so behind on C standards :-) Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: In C89, the common way to print the result of `sizeof` is to use `%lu` conversion specification with `sizeof` casted to `unsigned long`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight perhaps it isn't and the fault is me: MSVC++ 9.0 freebie ;-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you are right, there is no mention of `z` here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

```
sizeof(x)
```

is the size of an array object. Its value is `10 * sizeof (int)`.

```
sizeof(p_x)
```

is the size of a pointer object. Its value is `sizeof (int *)`.

Answer (score 4):

sizeof(x) returns the size of your array in Bytes (10*sizeof(int), sizeof int is 4 bytes), while sizeof(p_x) returns the size of a pointer. If youre using a 64 bit machine, thats 8 bytes, if its a 32 bit machine, its 4 bytes.